# Bash variable in Awk script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have this flat file database(ff_servers.db) with following contents:

```
192.168.154.2 Alaska   hp
192.168.157.3 Colorado dell
192.168.156.3 hawaii   hp
```

From command line, I could run:

```
awk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/alaska/ {print $NF}" ff_servers.db`
```

and I would get

```
hp
```

However, from a bash script, I'm having problems with "$NF"
Here's the dump of that script:

```
machine_type=`awk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/${server_name}/ {print \$NF}" ff_servers.db`
awk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/${server_name}/ {print $NF}" ff_servers.db
++ awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/colorado/ {print }' ff_servers.db
+ target_arch='192.168.157.3   Colorado           dell'
```

So obviously, $NF is not being translated properly. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the standard `"$()"` format to ensure more conventional quoting behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Bash expands variables (such as identifiers beginning with `$`) within double quotes `"`.

Although this should have also been a problem when doing this interactively from the commmand line.
Bash will try expand `"$NF"`, if the variable `NF` isn't defined then bash will expand this to the empty string.

Usually you can use single quotes `'` so that `$NF` will not be expanded by bash.

However since you want `${server_name}` to expand, you can try double escaping

```
machine_type=`awk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/${server_name}/ {print \\$NF}" ff_servers.db`
```

You could also try using string concatenation, the difference is mostly stylistic.

```
machine_type=`awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/'${server_name}'/{print $NF}' ff_servers.db`
```

This works as bash will concatenate adjacent strings together.

Comment: thanks for the help. I figured out the answer myself as I was fiddling with my script. As I had the need for $server_name to be a variable, I had this instead: `machine_type=`awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}/'${server_name}'/ {print $NF}' ff_servers.db` `coz if I would leave it as you suggested, $server_name would then be interpreted not as a variable but a constant with $ sign.

Comment: I was just in the process of writing about string concatenation as a possible solution :)

Comment: I prefer to not mess up the code with escaping: `machine_type=$(awk -vserver_name="$server_name" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}$0~server_name{print $NF}' ff_servers.db)`.

Comment: @manatwork, can you clarify your solution please? I can't seem to make it work. Maybe on a separate answer instead of a comment as it breaks some statements

Comment: See here: http://pastebin.com/LPsLG4xz What kind of `awk` you use?

Comment: @manatwork, I'm using gawk (as I'm on RHEL 5.4)

Comment: I also use `gawk` and it works for me. Post a failed attempt in a pastebin so we can see _how_ it not works. (Given that you quoted no error message or incorrect output, is impossible to debug your problem.)